# Text editor for Retina MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, text-editors

I mostly type in gedit, but the blurry text on this new laptop is driving me nuts. I'm not looking for features in a text editor beyond sharp text.

Suggestions?

EDIT: Thanks for all the suggestions. I like Sublime Text best, but Scrivener seems like a great tool for complex, revision-heavy documents.

- [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)
- [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php?platform=mac)
- [Textmate](http://macromates.com/)

Comment: There's a [similar question about IDEs that support retina displays at Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/is-there-a-retina-enabled-ide-to-do-some-programming-on-the-new-macbook-pro). Couldn't you just use TextEdit or the other native text editors like it?

Comment: I'm closing this now since over time all text editors will be Retina-ready and we'll have a list of all text editors for OS X. Most major ones are ready anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).  From their website:

> Sublime Text is a sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose.
>   You'll love the slick user interface, extraordinary features and amazing performance.

It supports Retina displays for OS X since version 2.0.

It has a commercial license but can be downloaded for evaluation (full-featured) with no enforced time-limit.

Comment: Sublime text doesn't have very smart indentation, and lacks in a lot of ways. I'd suggest the most simple editor possible, over one that has just enough extras to leave you desiring more.

Answer (score 2):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) supports retina displays, as does my favorite [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php?platform=mac).

Answer (score 1):

The terminal-based text editors look beautiful on retina display.
However, [TextMate](https://github.com/textmate/textmate) is open source now. 
Build it and you'll have a wonderful retina-ready interface (except a couple icons in the file browser).